# NSObjectInaccessbileExceptions while merging child context

Tags: ios, core-data

I understand about NSObjectInaccessbileExceptions in general, and the need to avoid attempting to fault in an object that has been deleted in another managed context/thread.

However, in my user crash reports, I'm seeing an NSObjectInaccessibleException while merging/saving a child NSManagedObjectContext from a background thread (B) into my main context (A), which seems like an unusual scenario.

The only situation I can imagine that could cause such a thing is the following:

1. change property of object in thread/context (B)
2. delete object in thread/context A
3. save context A
4. save context B
5. merge A into B and save A -> exception raised because object doesn't exist in A.

Has anybody else seen an exception in while saving the context like this? I tried to reproduce this manually, but failed. Is there some other scenario where this could happen, and are there any tips for dealing with such?

Thanks!

```
Fatal Exception
NSObjectInaccessibleException
CoreData could not fulfill a fault for '0x1f019da0 <x-coredata://741E65A8-C211-470E-8194-3005F0DFA71C/TrackInfo/p265>'
0   CoreFoundation  __exceptionPreprocess + 162
1   libobjc.A.dylib     objc_exception_throw + 30
2   CoreData    _PFFaultHandlerLookupRow + 1482
3   CoreData    -[NSFaultHandler fulfillFault:withContext:] + 24
4   CoreData    -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _updateFromRefreshSnapshot:includingTransients:] + 236
5   CoreData    -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) _copyChildObject:toParentObject:fromChildContext:] + 96
6   CoreData    -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) _parentProcessSaveRequest:inContext:error:] + 918
7   CoreData    __82-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) executeRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke_0 + 564
8   libdispatch.dylib   _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow_invoke + 96
9   libdispatch.dylib   _dispatch_client_callout + 22
10  libdispatch.dylib   _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 228
11  CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopRun + 1288
12  CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
13  CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
14  GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal + 74
15  UIKit   UIApplicationMain + 1120
16  app    main.m line 13    main
17  app    start
```

Comment: Did you get any solution for this issue?

Comment: I would start by evaluating your use case for child contexts. Most of the time, they're used incorrectly, or for 'concurrency' which isn't really concurrent for IO. http://benedictcohen.co.uk/blog/archives/308

Answer (score 0):

You may try using the following line while you are creating your child context:

```
privateManagedObjectContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy
```